# creating a validation script for a submission form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have created a submission form using Expression engine's plugin freeform, everything is working in terms of submission, the only issue i am having is the valuation side of things.

Is there a way to validate my script before submission, i.e pick up things as unfilled fields, incorrect emails etc..

below is a snippet of my code.

JQUERY

```
var form = $('#ajax-contact');
var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

$(form).submit(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
var formData = $(form).serialize();

// Submit the form using AJAX.
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(form).attr('action'),
    data: formData
})
.done(function(response) {

    if (response.success) {
        formMessages.removeClass('error').addClass('success').text("Thank you for submitting your details");
          $('.valFields').val("");
     } else {
      formMessages.removeClass("success").addClass("error").text("Oops, Please check your details");
   }

})


.fail(function(data) {
    // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
    $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
    $(formMessages).addClass('error');

    // Set the message text.
    if (data.responseText !== '') {
        $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
    } else {
        $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
    }
});

 })

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="form-messages">



        {exp:freeform:form 
            form_id="1"
            admin_notify="myemail@.me.com"
            form:class="main-contact submit-fade ajax-form"
            form:id="ajax-contact"


        }

            <ul class="small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-2 hide-form">
               <li>
                  <label for="name">Name</label>
                  {freeform:field:first_name
                      attr:class="form-control valFields" 
                      attr:placeholder="First Name" 
                      attr:class="required"
                  }

                </li>

                <li>
                  <label for="email">Email</label>
                  {freeform:field:email
                      attr:class="form-control valFields" 
                      attr:placeholder="Email" 
                      attr:class="required"
                  }
                 </li>
              </ul>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success">

        {/exp:freeform:form}

      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: To perform pre-submission validation, simply validate first, and then perform a check on the validation status—if successful, perform AJAX call; if not, do otherwise.

Comment: Several jQuery form validation plugins can help you, such as http://jqueryvalidation.org/.

Answer (score -1):

Validation of fields can done calling a function

**Call Validate function `onSubmit action` and if successful perform the submission of form using `AJAX`**.

```
Example:

<script>
  $(form).submit(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  var check = validate();
  if(check){
   var formData = $(form).serialize();
   ..
   //form sumit using AJAX
   ..
 }

 function validate()
      {
         if( document.myForm.Name.value == "" )
         {
            alert( "Please provide your name!" );
            document.myForm.Name.focus() ;
            return false;
         }

         if( document.myForm.EMail.value == "" ) 
         {
            alert( "Please provide your Email!" );
            document.myForm.EMail.focus() ;
            return false;
         }
         return true;
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The better way of doing this is putting types in inputs

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-2 hide-form">
           <li>
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              {freeform:field:first_name
                  attr:class="form-control valFields" 
                  attr:placeholder="First Name" 
                  attr:required="required"
              }

            </li>

            <li>
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              {freeform:field:email
                  attr:class="form-control valFields" 
                  attr:placeholder="Email" 
                  attr:required="required",
                  attr:type="email"
              }
             </li>
          </ul>
```

It will not only make sure that the fields are not left empty but also will check the valid email type.